# How to connect MySQL database through two SSH hosts

Tags: mysql, ssh

How do I connect to MySQL database through two SSH hosts ?

Here is my situation: I have two SSH hosts as show below. MySQL is running in BOX2 host.

```
MyBox(MySQL GUI client) -----SSH(port 22)--->BOX1(IP: 190.xx.xx.xx)---SSH(port 22)--->BOX2(IP: 190.xx.xx.xx)[MySQL server]
```

My question is how do I connect if I have multiple SSH hosts to tunnel as shown above ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will help. Try this command from MyBox (having the MySQL Client)

```
ssh user@box1 -L some-local-port:box2:22
```

Now from the Client try to connect to connect this way

```
MySQL host : localhost
MySQL usernmae : mysql-username-of-server-installed-at-Box2
MySQL password : mysql-password-of-server-installed-at-Box2
MySQL port : 3306 (suppose mysql server at Box-2 is listening at port 3306)
```

In tunnelling info

```
SSH host : localhost
SSH pass : ssh-password-of-Box2
SSH port : some-local-port
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
ssh -L 33306:localhost:33306 user@box1_hostname ssh -L 33306:localhost:3306 user@box2_hostname
```

Then try connecting to mysql using 127.0.0.1:33306. Note that port 33306 will be available to anyone on box1 which may or may not be an issue for you.

Another way to accomplish the same is to use ProxyCommand as explained [here](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/03/1916/).

Answer (score 0):

My alternate solution using a Putty client is as below.

1. First configure a tunnel from MyBox port 3300 to Box1 port 3300 on Putty application.
2. Connect Putty to Box 1
3. Type below command to establish tunnel between Box1 and Box2
   ssh -L 3300:localhost:3306 root@Box2_IP
4. Connect Mysql client to localhost:3300

Putty Config screenshots as below.
[image: Puttuy Config Connect Screen]

[image: Putty Tunnel Config Screen]